# Search for an Array from a UICollectionView

Tags: arrays, swift, search, uicollectionview, searchbar

I am making an app in which the user can search for the name of an image in a UICollectionView. Currently, the user can name each image, and the names get stored to an array called arrayOfName.

I have added a search bar where I can successfully test for its text using:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {


        if (searchText.lowercased() == "test") {


            print("TEST")

        }
}
```

and

```
func addImgNames() {
        for _ in 0...20 {
            imgNames.append("imageNames")
        }

    }
```

This is now the user names the images:

```
let arrayOfNames = defaults.object(forKey: "imageNames") as? [Optional] ?? [String]()

        if let nameOfImage = (arrayOfNames[imgCell]) {
          self.navigationItem.title = nameOfImage
```

In addition, the search bar delegate and the arrayOfNames function are in two sperate classes, which makes it that much more difficult.

How can I test for a name that is stored in the array?

Thanks!!

Comment: You should filter your array, for example: 
arrayOfNames.filter {$0.contains(searchText.lowercased())}

Comment: @MagoNicolasPalacios arrayOfNames is not universal... so I don't know what to do.

Comment: maybe you should make it universal for being able to access it anywhere, otherwise, if you are changing views you can pass it while performing segue.

Comment: @MagoNicolasPalacios I don't know how to do that... Would you mind writing up an answer, please?

Comment: I might be able to help but you will need to provide more code of your other classes and how you are getting to the search screen.

Comment: @Timmy do you have an email I could reach you at? I dont wanna display all of my code here.

Comment: Stack overflow is here to help everyone, privately emailing you defeats this purpose so if you want help you have to post your code here.

Comment: @Timmy I just dont want people to steal the code

Comment: I see that you have accepted an answer, but to continue on what I was saying, I will answer your question only here on stack overflow. Your question could be someone else's and an answer would help them. This community is about sharing and helping, not about privately answering questions and leaving other people in the dark wondering how to solve their problem. We are not here to steal your code, trust me, we are here so that everyone can ask questions and receive answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should filter your array, for example:

```
arrayOfNames.filter {$0.searchInfo.contains(searchText.lowercased())}
```

And for accessing arrayOfNames, you can make it global, or just pass it if you change your view with a performWithSegue and a prepareForSegue.